# How to assure I am testing everything, I have all the features and only those features for old code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, cucumber

We are running a pretty big website, we have some critical legacy code there we want to have well covered.

At the same time we would like to have a report of the features we are currently supporting and covered.  And also we want to be sure we really cover every possible corner case. Some code paths are critical and will need many more tests even after achieving 100% coverage.

As we are already using rspec and rspec has "feature" and "scenario" keywords, we tried to make a list using rspec rather than going for cucumber but I think this question can be applied to any testing tool.

We want something like this:

```
feature "each advertisement will be shown a specified % of impressions" 
  scenario "As ..."
```

This feature is minimal from the point of view of managers but huge in the code. It involves a backend tool, a periodic task, logic in the models and views in backend and front end. 
We tried to divide it like this:

```
feature "each creative will be shown a specified % of impressions" 
   context "configuration"
     context "display"
      scenario "..."
     context "models"
      it "should ..."
   context "frontend"
    context "display"
      scenario "..."
    context "models"
      it "should ..."
```

Configuration takes place in another tool, display would contain integration tests and models would contain unit test.

I repeat myself but the idea is sto assure that the feature is really finished(including building the configuration tool) and 100% tested.

But looking at this file, it is not integration, nor unit test not even belong to any particular project. 
Definitely there should be a better way of managing this.

Any experiences, resources, ideas you can share to guide us ?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you're describing is a huge reason why BDD is so popular. It forces you to write code in a way that's easy to test. Having said that, you're obviously not going to go back and rewrite the entire legacy application. There are a few things you should consider though:

- As you go through each section of the application, you should ask yourself 'Will it be harder to refactor than to write tests for this?'. Sometimes refactoring before writing tests just cannot be avoided.
- Testing isn't about 100% coverage, it's about 100% confidence. As you mentioned, you plan on writing more tests even when you have 100% coverage. This is because you're going for confidence. Once you're confident in a piece of code, move on. You can always come back to it at a later time.
- From my experience, Cucumber is easier for tests that cover a large portion of the application. I think the reason for this is that writing out the tests in plain english makes you think of things you wouldn't have otherwise. It also allows you to focus on the behavior instead of the code and can make refactoring a less daunting task.
- You don't really get much out of adding tests to existing code if you never touch that code again. Start with testing the code you want to make changes (i.e. refactor) to first.

I also recommend the book [Rails Test Prescriptions](http://pragprog.com/book/nrtest/rails-test-prescriptions), specifically one of the last chapters called "Testing a Legacy Application".